# Get Duplicate Id and add all the Data in one id

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, filter

I want to extract the object of same title and add all the data to one object.

```
 new = [{
        "data": [{ "displayName": "Peter pvt ltd", "name": "Peter Zon"}],
        "title": "9/9/2020",
    },{
        "data": [{ "displayName": "Tom pvt ltd", "name": "Tom wang", }, { "displayName": "parker pvt ltd", "name": "parker wing", }],
        "title": "9/9/2020", 
    }]
```

I want something like below:

```
new = [{
        "data": [{ "displayName": "Peter pvt ltd", "name": "Peter Zon", }, { "displayName": "Tom pvt ltd", "name": "Tom wang", }, { "displayName": "parker pvt ltd", "name": "parker wing", }],
        "title": "9/9/2020",
    }]
```

Comment: Just search for: _"javascript array of objects group by"_

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: const lookup = newArray.reduce((a, e) => {
            a[e.title] = ++a[e.title] || 0;
            return a;
          }, {});    newArray.filter(e => lookup[e.title])

Comment: It is returning duplicate data, instead i need to return all data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group object array using **Array.reduce** method in javascript.

```
const objects = [{
        "data": [{ "displayName": "Peter pvt ltd", "name": "Peter Zon"}],
        "title": "9/9/2020",
    },{
        "data": [{ "displayName": "Tom pvt ltd", "name": "Tom wang", }, { "displayName": "parker pvt ltd", "name": "parker wing", }],
        "title": "9/9/2020", 
    }]

objects.reduce((acc,curr) => {
    const target = acc.find(item => curr.title === item.title); 
    if(target) {
      target.data = [...target.data, ...curr.data];
    } else {
       acc.push(curr);
    }
    return acc;
}, []);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was life saving for me. Your solution worked perfectly. This is the thing i was looking for.

Comment: Glad it solved your problem. Please mark as accepted if it helped you.